How to convert strings to function parameters in Elixir
I have a list like this: str_list=["x","y","z"], I want to convert them and use them like def f(x,y,z | tail) do ... end, that means the parameter names of function f are from and the same as the elements in list str_list .
What shall I do?

While it’s possible, I strongly discourage you from doing that. This is never needed and always might be done in a less cryptic more readable and maintainable manner.

Are you trying to define a function that way, or invoke it?  If it's a call, with what parameters?  Why do it this specific way?

If you really want to do this, look at https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12.3/Kernel.html#apply/3
However I would also discourage doing this. It is usually not a good idea. Why not simply pass the list as a single argument?

@David Maze I'd like to define a function, or make a pattern like this [x,y,z | tail] = alist. I do this for the reason of reading a text-format table and get the table head which will be used by function or pattern  to acquire some data from the table. PS, "x", "y", "z" are column names of the table.

@lyl it is impossible to store pattern in variable
